# Show spell range when using quick cast

Tags: league-of-legends

I was playing fiddlesticks and wanted to know my Ult exact range to excel my positioning for a gank and I was wondering

When using Quickcast, is there a way to show the **spells range** using the keyboard ( similar to moving mouse cursor on spell )

Answer (score 6):

There is an option that when turned on shows the spells range as long as you keep the button pressed. The skills will then be cast on key release. Can't point you to the exact location of the option at the moment.

But I personally don't like using it. The skills are cast on key release and not on key press. That means skills are often cast a bit later then without this option on.

If i have trouble determining a champions skill range i often just go into custom and play that champion once or twice. Just to get a "feel" of the ranges.

Comment: sorry, It's not the answer I'm looking for. I wanna keep using QuickCast but have an option to check range with something like Ctrl+R or something similar

Comment: @ItaySela I think this is the best answer you're going to get, since there aren't any other options. Besides, you still have quick cast, the cast is just activated on key up rather than key down.

Comment: problem is with fiddlestick ( for example ) if I use the quickcast out of range, I might run out of the brush to use my ultimate and lose the element of surprise. so If you're right then there is no feature like the one I'm for

Comment: Well maybe there is another option. The config file league uses can be used for some pretty neat things, like allowing multiple key bindings do the same thing. You could try to map some keys in a way that you have normal and quickcast at the same time. Need to know the range? use the normal cast.

Comment: That's something I hadn't thought about @Gnarly404. You might be able to still custom bind the normal cast to ctrl+button so that you can see the range.

Comment: I use the option Gnarly is talking about and it works well, it also doesn't really slow you down since the press release can be pretty fast.